# Observable: Checking if returned value is empty or not

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, observable

## What I want to do:

I'm checking in DB if there is a matching date. If there is a match, it gets send back.
I do this with a GET request.

In my .ts class I then want to look if the returned value is empty or not.

### This is my code:

recommended-section.service.ts

```
checkRetValue(recommendedSection: RecommendedSection): boolean{

        var checkNumber = this.checkOverlappingDates(recommendedSection);
    }

async checkOverlappingDates (recommendedSection: RecommendedSection) {
        var copy = this.convert(recommendedSection);
        var localeArray = [];
        recommendedSection.recommendedSectionNames.forEach( (rsn) => {
            localeArray.push(rsn.locale.id);
        });

        await this.activeFromActiveToQuery({
                active_from: copy.activeFrom,
                active_to: copy.activeTo,
                locale_ids: localeArray
            }).subscribe((data) => {
                var retNumber;
                if (data.json == "") {
                    retNumber = 1;
                } else {
                    retNumber = 0;
                }

                return retNumber;

            }), (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json);

    }

activeFromActiveToQuery(req?: any): Observable<ResponseWrapper>{
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        options.params.append("active_from", req.active_from);
        options.params.append("active_to", req.active_to);
        options.params.append("locale_ids", req.locale_ids);

        return this.http.get(this.resourceActiveFromActiveToURL, options)
            .map(res => {
                return res.json();
            });
    }
```

### My Problem:

Is it possible to get `retNumber` returned to the function `checkRetValue`?

I've tried a lot of suggestions but I couldn't finde one that made it work for me.

Comment: have you tried returning the subscribe function return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different solutions, this worked for me:

```
async checkOverlappingDates(recommendedSection: RecommendedSection) {
        var copy = this.convert(recommendedSection);
        var localeArray = [];
        recommendedSection.recommendedSectionNames.forEach((rsn) => { localeArray.push(rsn.locale.id); });

        var tester = await this.activeFromActiveToQuery({
            active_from: copy.activeFrom,
            active_to: copy.activeTo,
            locale_ids: localeArray
        }).first().toPromise();
```

Instead of using the subscribe() method I used `.first().toPromise()`.

This may not be the best answer but for now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map method in the pipeline to transform the result and then return the observable which use will resolve to a number.

Comment: Yes this worked. But I still can't hand the value of `data` in `checkOverlappingDates` which is now a number if I print it in the console. But if I want to hand it to variable with type number I get the following error: _Type 'ResponseWrapper' is not assignable to type 'number'._

Comment: You can change the output: (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json).
Instead of returning the this.onError(res.json), you can return a default number and log the error.